# Encountering 401 Error When Accessing JIRA Agile Boards via OAuth 2.0 (3LO)

Tags: oauth-2.0, jira, jira-agile

I'm working on integrating with JIRA's Agile boards via the JIRA REST API (specifically the endpoint https://your-domain.atlassian.com/rest/agile/1.0/board). I'm using the OAuth 2.0 (3LO) flow for authentication and authorization, as described in Atlassian's documentation.

Despite the below steps, when trying to access the Agile boards, I receive a 401 Unauthorized error with the following message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<status>
    <status-code>401</status-code>
    <message>Client must be authenticated to access this resource.</message>
</status>`
```

Created an Atlassian app and configured the necessary scopes and redirect URL.
Successfully received a callback and an authorization code.
Exchanged the authorization code for an access token.
Verified that the token includes the following scopes:

`read:dashboard:jira`
`read:project:jira`
`read:board-scope:jira-software`
`read:issue:jira-software`
`read:sprint:jira-software`

Comment: Are you sure that you're passing the access token in the authorization header (Bearer) as shown in the documentation (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/user-impersonation-for-connect-apps/)?